# How to deploy secure Jersey application to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jersey, grizzly

It was easy to figure out how to deploy a Jersey application, which uses Grizzly, to Heroku. Once I got the basic app up, I decided to follow the instructions laid out by the [https-clientserver-grizzly](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/https-clientserver-grizzly) example to secure my endpoint, but have run into some issues deploying it to Heroku.

Once deployed to Heroku the server refuses to respond, closing all connection requests without sending a response. Locally I have no issue, it's only when I deploy to Heroku that this error occurs.

I've included the pertinent parts of my **Server.java** file below.

```
public class Server extends ResourceConfig {
    private static final String DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = "8443";
    private static final String KEY_SERVER_PORT = "server.port";
    private static final String KEY_TRUST_PASSWORD = "TRUST_PASSWORD";
    private static final String KEYSTORE_SERVER_FILE = "./security/keystore_server";
    private static final String LOCALHOST = "https://0.0.0.0:%s/v1";
    private static final String TRUSTSTORE_SERVER_FILE = "./security/truststore_server";

    private final String endpoint;
    private final HttpServer httpServer;

    private Server(final String endpoint) throws KeyManagementException, 
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
            FileNotFoundException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super();

        ...

        URI.create(this.endpoint),
                this,
                true,
                secure());

        this.httpServer.start();

        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Jersey app started with WADL available at %s/application.wadl",
                this.endpoint));
    }


    /**
     * Generates a secure configurator for the server.
     * @return A {@link SSLEngineConfigurator} instance for the server.
     * @throws IOException If the key or trust store password cannot be read.
     * @throws RuntimeException If the configuration is considered invalid.
     */
    private static SSLEngineConfigurator secure() throws IOException, RuntimeException {
        // Set up security context
        final String password = System.getenv(KEY_TRUST_PASSWORD);
        if (password == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Truststore password is not set in the environment");
        }

        // Grizzly ssl configuration
        SSLContextConfigurator sslContext = new SSLContextConfigurator();

        // set up security context
        sslContext.setKeyStoreFile(KEYSTORE_SERVER_FILE); // contains server keypair
        sslContext.setKeyStorePass(password);
        sslContext.setTrustStoreFile(TRUSTSTORE_SERVER_FILE); // contains client certificate
        sslContext.setTrustStorePass(password);
        sslContext.setSecurityProtocol("TLS");

        if (!sslContext.validateConfiguration(true)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SSL context is invalid");
        }

        return new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContext)
                .setClientMode(false)
                .setNeedClientAuth(false);
    }
}
```

If anyone has fought through this and has any suggestions it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku you don't need to set up HTTPS in your Java app yourself. Heroku handles HTTPS for you and SSL termination happens at the Heroku router, so traffic is unencrypted when it reaches your app.

Just access your site as https://.herokuapp.com

Comment: So then how might I go about rejecting or rerouting all unecrypted traffic?

Comment: That's a different question, and it depends on your server and some other things. Here is an example with Tomcat https://github.com/kissaten/tomcat-disable-http

Comment: The important part is here https://github.com/kissaten/tomcat-disable-http/blob/master/src/main/java/ForwardHttpFilter.java

Comment: I was under the impression it's poor form to forward http to https, but rather to decline the http request and respond with an informative header.

Thanks for the info, I suppose I'll have to do some creative header parsing or something to determine if heroku intercepted the encrypted request and is forwarding the traffic to my application.